# ComboBox Style problems with DisplayMemberPath

Tags: wpf, templates, combobox, styles, selecteditem

I have a ComboBox and I have set the **combo.ItemsSource** property to a **List** object. The **Book** class contains two properties: *"Abbreviation"* and *"Name".*

I have set the ComboBox's **DisplayMemberPath** to "**Abbreviation**" but the following style that is set on the ComboBox does not display the Abbreviation property, but instead shows "*Words.Book*" which is the name of the class. The ComboBox drop-down displays a list correctly (Using the specified **Abbreviation** property). The problem is in the **selected ComboBox item**, the one displayed when the ComboBox' drop-down is closed.

I guess the problem is in ContentPresenter in DataTemplate but I was unable to find a successful solution. Currently the ContentPresenter's **Content** property is set to Content="{TemplateBinding Content} but I don't know if that's how it should be.

Any ideas how to show the property specified in DisplayMemberPath on the selected item?

Thank you

the code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource ribbonTitleFade}" />
        <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" Margin="1,6,1,6" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource boSecE}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
              />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ribbonTitleFade}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ribbonTitleFade}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="comboBoxBorderTransparent" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource boPrimC}" />
</Style>


<Style x:Key="comboItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="backBorder" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectA" Stroke="White" Width="4" Height="4" Fill="#80FFFFFF" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="text" Foreground="White" FontSize="10px">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="8,1,0,1"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="rectA" Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter TargetName="rectA" Property="Fill" Value="#80000000" />
                        <Setter TargetName="backBorder" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource boPrimC}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="comboSelectedItemTemplate">
    <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="10px">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="60"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource comboItemStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton 
                        Name="ToggleButton" Grid.Column="2" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Name="ContentSite"
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource comboSelectedItemTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                      Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                      />

                    <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                           AllowsTransparency="False" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{DynamicResource ribbonTitleFade}"
                                    BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource boPrimC}" />
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <!--<Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>-->
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something more like this in your `ComboBox` template:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}"
 ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
 ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
 Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
 HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
 VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
 SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
```

Comment: I have changed the Content, ContentTemplate and ContentStringFormat as you suggested and it started displaying it as it should. Now, the only problem is that I don't know where to set that the Foreground brush for the text should be white. I previously did that in the DataTemplate, but as this DataTemplate is not used anymore, where would be the right place to place the Foreground="White"? Thanx

Comment: I think you could just put a Trigger on the ComboBoxItem.ItemContainerStyle which changes the Foreground to White when IsSelected = true.

Comment: The ComboBoxItem.ItemContainerStyle reflects the item in the drop-down list. What I need is a Foreground for selected item (when the drop-down is closed). 

Currently, this is set: ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" but I don't know how to change the ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate.

Comment: try:
ContentTemplateSelector={TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}
if you use the same Controltemplate as for the Popup

Answer (score 0):

If your template doesn't explicitly handles the value of `DisplayMemberPath`, then the template won't use it to change the `ComboBoxItem`. You'll have to bind to the member directly in the `ControlTemplate`, or use a separate `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem with the *BureauBlack theme* where it would just not apply the **DisplayMemberPath**, just showed the object name. I had a window with many (15+) ComboBoxes and all but 2 worked correctly using DisplayMemberPath.

I removed the following from the ContentPresenters and GridViewRowPresenters:

```
Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
```

in **ListBoxItem, ComboBoxItem,ListViewItem**. There may be more that need fixed, but this was all we found that we are using.

Using Microsoft.Net 4.0 Framework. I did not try on 4.5 or 3.5.