# WPF Combobox style will not change when DisplayMemberPath is set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

So i've looked around but have been unable to find an answer to this issue. I am trying to style a combobox that has DisplayMemberPath. As long as that field is set the fontsize that I set has no effect on the combobox. I've also tried applying template styles, but the results are the same for the font. The question/answer listed in question "ComboBox Style problems with DisplayMemberPath" doesn't address fontsize but appears to be more geared to resulting colors.

Here is the combobox:

```
<ComboBox 
Grid.Row="0" 
Height="36" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" 
ItemsSource="{Binding VideoDeviceFilters}" 
SelectedValue="{Binding VideoDeviceFilter}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
Margin="0,11.857,1.333,11.856" 
Grid.Column="1"
TextBlock.FontSize="18.333"/>
```

And here is the combobox without the displaymemberpath:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" 
Height="35" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" 
Margin="0,12.857,1.333,11.856" 
ItemsSource="{Binding InstalledPrinters}" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Printer}" 
Grid.Column="1" 
TextBlock.FontSize="18.333"/>
```

Here is also the style declared in the view:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="ItemBorder" Padding="2,0"  BorderThickness="1"  CornerRadius="3" TextBlock.FontSize="18.333" >
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.

And here is the result: 
[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqLLb.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ComboBox Style problems with DisplayMemberPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785352/combobox-style-problems-with-displaymemberpath)

Comment: You need to show us where have you declared the `Style` for the `ComboBox` if I am not mistaken, when you declare `DisplayMemeberPath` the Displayed text is then not part of a visual tree and therefore not evaluated.